# Print the count of odd numbers in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to both find all the odd numbers between 39 and 150, using `for` loop, and print the count of odd numbers found.

What I did is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 39...150
        {
            if i % 2 != 0
            {
                print(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

I managed to print all of the odd numbers but I don't know how to print the count of the odd numbers.
How do I do that?

Comment: add `var count = 0` before your loops and do `count += 1` every time you find an odd number.  You could directly compute it `let count = (150 - 39 + 1)/2`

Comment: @vacawama: That would require *math* :)

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks.

Comment: Or you could initialize an initially empty vector and then fill it with all the odd numbers and do `vector.count` Altternatively, there is one odd number for every even so just divide n by 2

Comment: @ניקסלובודסקי please mark answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

According to newly released **Swift 5** you can determine this using `filter` and [isMultiple(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple) method

```swift
let count = Array(39...150).filter { !$0.isMultiple(of: 2) }.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` or `filter`

```
  let countOdd1 = Array(39...150).reduce(0) {$0 + ($1 % 2)}
  let countOdd2 = Array(39...150).filter { $0 % 2 != 0}.count

      print(countOdd1,countOdd2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways but according to your coding, you can achieve to do that:

```
   var addNUmbers = [Int]()
    for i in 39...150
    {
        if i % 2 != 0
        {
            addNUmbers.append(i)
            print(i)
        }
    }
    //Odd numbers count
    let oddNumbercount = addNUmbers.count
```

Or

```
     var addNUmbers = 0
        for i in 39...150
        {
            if i % 2 != 0
            {
                addNUmbers += 1
                print(i)
            }
        }
    //Odd numbers count
        print(addNUmbers)
```

Comment: @MartinR Yes , we can go with this, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let openRange = 0...50

for i in openRange where  i % 2 == 1 {
 print("Odd number \(i)")
}
```

Explanation:  This is conditional "for" loop which executes the block of code when 1%2 == 1 "which is an odd number" is met.

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it helps.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah, very correct, I will improve on this going forward, so this is conditional "for" loop which executes the block of code when 1%2 == 1 "which is an odd number" is met.

Comment: Please [edit] to add that to the answer, instead of hiding it here among the comments.